# How do you delete a key-value pair from a hash in ruby? I get an error when trying?

Tags: ruby

```
myhash = {answer: "yes", something: hello, another: "yes"}
myhash.delete[another]
```

I want to delete the another key-value pair. But, ruby gives me an error saying wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). What's going on?

Comment: i think its expecting index here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the method delete is a method, not an element on the hash , and another key is a symbol, so you should call on this form

```
 myhash.delete(:another)
```

Comment: Hmm, it still throws the error.

Comment: @someone you have to replace `another` with `:another` and `[...]` with `(...)`

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks!